# Shortest Path using Neo4j, with relationships of Start and End Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I'm fairly new to Neo4j. I'm trying to get the shortest path for default movie database.
However, along with it I also need the start and end node(of type Person) to display there first level relation to any other node and if any person node on the path have a relation to the start and end node via some other node. Its better to explain with below pictures.

Normal shortestpath will look, something like this.
[image]

```
MATCH (p1:Person { name: 'Kevin Bacon' }),(p2:Person { name: 'Meg Ryan' }),
p = shortestPath((p1)-[*..15]-(p2))
return p
```

However my desired output is this one.
[image]

I tried below cypher. However i cannot understand, how to do it. I'm getting below result, which is incorrect.

```
MATCH (p1:Person { name: 'Kevin Bacon' }),(p2:Person { name: 'Meg Ryan' }),
p = shortestPath((p1)-[*..15]-(p2))
MATCH (p1:Person)-[r]-(b)  // here i need foreach node on path for type person, get there relationships? However can't do that
return p,p1,r,b
```

[image]

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the movies in the start and end nodes of shortest path. Then add the movies with the path.

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((p1:Person { name: 'Kevin Bacon' })-[*..15]-(p2:Person { name: 'Meg Ryan' })) 
WITH p1, p2, p
MATCH (p1)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m1) 
MATCH (p2)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2) 
RETURN p, m1, m2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you have a look, still something is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Jose. It's close.  I don''t want to restrict the relation just to "ACTED_IN"  with (Movie). I just did a small modification.

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((p1:Person { name: 'Kevin Bacon' })-[*..15]- 
      (p2:Person { name: 'Meg Ryan' })) 
      UNWIND nodes(p) as n 
      MATCH (n)-[*]->(q) 
      RETURN n, q
```

[image]

However, i don't need the nodes highlighted in the box as they are not related to Meg and Kevin. Not sure how to exclude them.